# Printing user input string between another string

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

In the beginning of my code, I have a welcome title in which I'm trying to insert the name of someone inbetween.
The problem is that the second part of the welcome phrase is sent below the first welcome phrase and the name.
My goal is to get the full welcome phrase in the same line

```
.data
    title1: .asciiz "Welcome "
    Name: .asciiz "Insert your name \n"
    Username: .space 10
    title2: .asciiz  "to a quiz about Comouter Science and Engineering!\n"


.text

    li $v0, 4            #Display insert name phrase
    la $a0, Name
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 8              #Input User name
    la $a0, Username
    li $a1, 20
    syscall
    
# Show full Welcome  phrase
    li $v0, 4 # Prepare system call for print string
    la $a0, title1 # Prepare string to print
    syscall # Print the string 

    li $v0, 4
    la Sa0, Username
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la Sa0, title2
    syscall
```

This is the outcome

Insert your name:

John Doe

Welcome John Doe

to a quiz about Computer Science and Engineering!

Comment: does the username contain newlines after it is filled in?

Comment: I didn't put any `\n` , so I think not

Comment: When you type the name, you put Enter at the end, right? That newline is left in the string.

Comment: Why do you reserve 10 bytes for Username, but in the syscall you say it’s 20?

Comment: So if I type my name, automatically adds a newline? How can I prevent this? HAve other suggestions on how I should approach this?

Comment: My mistake, its supposed to be 10

Comment: I don’t think you can prevent it. You have to find the newline and remove it from the string before printing it. If the syscall returns the number of bytes read, you can add that to the address of the buffer, subtract 1, and write a 0 there to truncate the string.

Answer (score 0):

The newline you see in the output is the newline you entered to end your input.
So before outputting the name you should find the first \n and replace that by a end of string character \0. After that it can be safely printed.

Comment: I took out all the newlines and the problem persists. I gather that the input automatically puts a newline and I cannot prevent it

Comment: then maybe the call to _syscall_ adds the newline. Is there no way to concatenate the strings before printing them in one go? Or is there a routine that prints without newline?

Comment: I also tried to attribute the second part of the message to $a1 and put right after the print of the username, but then the second message won't appear. Like this:
```li $v0, 4  la $a0, Username  la $a1, title2  syscall ```   @ruud

Comment: did you remove the newline after the username was read from the terminal? From the documentation it looks like syscall does not add new lines by itself.

Comment: I took all the newlines from every part of the code, still nothing

Comment: no not the code, from the string that was given as input. Try overwriting the say 3rd character of the inputstring with a null character before outputting. The string gets truncated including the suspected newline. If that works, you can put effort in finding the newline in that string; iff that does nothing, I am out of ideas.